# Understanding CLRS BFT lemma

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal

I was reading BFT from CLRS. This is the example given in the book:

[image]
(Figure:The operation of BFS on an undirected graph. Tree edges are shown shaded as they are produced by BFS. The value of $u.d$ appears within each vertex $u$. The queue $Q$ is shown at the beginning of each iteration. Vertex distances appear below vertices in the queue.)

Then it gives following lemma:

> Suppose that during the execution of BFS on a graph $G=(V,E)$, the queue $Q$
>   contains the vertices $<v_1,v_2,...,v_r>$, where $v_1$ is the head of $Q$ and $v_r$ is the tail. Then, $v_r.d\leq v_1.d+1$ and $v_i.d\leq v_{i+1}.d$ for $I=1,2,...,r-1$.

I am ok with $v_i.d\leq v_{i+1}.d$ for $I=1,2,...,r-1$ as I can observe this in all queue instances above. But I am not able to understand how $v_r.d\leq v_1.d+1$ aligns with above, as $i<i+1$, but $r>1$. How that $+1$ is making whole difference?

Comment: Which is it, BFT or BFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a tree like

```
        a           <-- level = 0
      / | \
     b  c  d        <-- level = 1
   /
  f                 <-- level = 2

    v1, v2, v3     
Q : b,  c,  d
    1,  1,  1

v3.d <= v1.d + 1   i.e 1 <= (1+1)
```

Now, suppose head of Q (i.e `b`) is removed and its neighbors are inserted in Q

```
    v1, v2, v3
Q : c,  d,  f
    1,  1,  2

v3.d <= v1.d + 1   i.e 2 <= (1+1)
```

This, `v3.d <= v1.d + 1` can be also be seen as `v3.d - v1.d <= 1` which means at any point of time distance between elements of queue will always be `less than or equal 1`. This can also be seen from the fact that during the execution of BFT only elements from 2 successive levels are present in queue. There cannot be case such that 2 elements `A` and `B` are present in queue with `A` at `level x` and `B` at `level (x + 2)`.

Comment: ohh so when $v_i,d \leq v_{i+1}.d$ is holding, both of them are at the same level and while $v_r.d\leq v_1.d+1$ is holding, $v_r$ is at deeper/higher level than $v_1$, Right?

Comment: @anir: Correct. Elements at head of queue have less than or equal distance from source compared to elements at tail. If `x` is some distance from source then queue can have following 3 patterns: [1] `x, x, x, ..., x`   [2] `x, x, x, x, ...x+1` [3] `x, x, x, ..., x+1, x+1,...,x+1`